# Access & SQL linked table Default Value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access

Question: How to EXPLICITLY get the default value to SHOW in a SQL/Access linked table?

Scenario:

- You are in an Access Table. One of the fields is labelled 'Collection
  Method'.
- The field is a list box with 2 values to choose from -Arrears or
  Advance
- Within the properties field, the default value is Advance
- In Datasheet view, the default value EXPLICITLY shows Advance for
  that field as opposed to a blank cell.

When linking the Access table to SQL, you cannot set the default value - Access shows a message in the properties window -  'the property cannot be modified in linked tables'.

If I go and set the default value in SQL, it does not explicitly show the value when the end user is inserting records for that row. They would either have to click on the list box and choose the value or if they left the field blank and went to the next record, then the SQL constraint would kick in and show the default value for the previous record.

Is there a way to show the default value explicitly?

Kind regards
D

Answer (score 2):

No, not really unless you adopt some "kluge" workarounds.

Access will not see nor set server things like say a PK (identity) field. In local tables, when you start typing, you can see the defaults, and the PK key is also seen (and seen before the record is committed).

When you use linked tables and server side defaults, or say an auto number PK (a PK + identity column in SQL server), then the value is NOT available until such time you save the record.

You certainly could get around this issue by using an access form, since editing tables directly in Access is a bad idea. However, this would mean you set the control defaults in the Access form control, and not in the table.

Last but not least, if this was a form, then you could turn off the allow additions to the form, and place a button on the form called “add new”. The code would add the record, and THEN set the form to that new record – this would display the default values. (But would result in a record being created if the user exits the form at that time without doing anything or wanting to add the record). So this can cause lots of "extra" blank records in your application.

So defaults server side and that of PK/identity values don’t show NOR ARE they set until such time you commit (save) the record in question.

During data entry you can also hit F9 to refresh the current record (this will ONLY work if the record is dirty – so the f9 will only work if you already done “some” data entry into the row. Note that ctrl-s to save the current record also works (and again only after the row in question has become dirty).

So users could hit ctrl-s, but really for reduction of torture, you best use a form - even a datasheet that looks like a table to deal with this issue.

Comment: It's not for forms (currently anyway). Thank you so much for that rich and helpful explanation. Due to the fact that the values don't show unless you commit the record, we opted to make the fields as NOT NULL in SQL, thereby forcing the user to make a selection from the blank field in the linked table, which  had default values that showed in the local tables before the record was committed.